# sed: escaped square closing bracket does not match

Tags: sed, regular-expression

Goal: replace `![alttext](url.png)` with `<img src="url.png" alt="alttext">`.

The `!` and `(...)` parts work fine, it's the `[...]` part that I can't get to work.

As a simple example, I want to match the input `a [test] b`. This is the command I use:

```
echo 'a [test] b' | sed 's/\[[^\]]*\]/x/'
```

It doesn't work. When I replace the square brackets with angle brackets, it works just fine:

```
echo 'a <test> b' | sed 's/<[^>]*>/x/'
```

Why does sed not understand the same regex but with escaped square brackets? It works fine in other tools such as Python.

Comment: It's a complex task to parse markdown. Here's the [commonmark spec](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.28/) for reference.

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks for the pointer, but I'm not trying to create a complete markdown parser. I just wanted a small shell script which replaces h1-h3, links, images, bold, italics, and paragraphs. That's just a few sed rules and makes a webpage readable so someone can semi-preview it without having to deploy it to the markdown-based CMS system.

Comment: IMO, it would be easier to just use a markdown tool to compile the markdown text into html, instead of rolling your own semi-solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Within the character class definition `]` is taken literally when directly following the `^`. So don't escape this. Also you are missing a quantifier like `+`, to say "one or more characters" or `*` to say "zero or more characters". Furthermore there is one `sed` too many in your command line.

```
$ echo 'a [test] b' | sed 's/\[[^]]\+\]/x/'
a x b
```

(`\+` being a GNU extension (now also supported by a few other implementations), the standard equivalent is `\{1,\}`)

or more readable:

```
$ echo 'a [test] b' | sed -E 's:\[[^]]+\]:x:'
a x b
```

(`-E` being a BSD extension, now also supported by GNU `sed` and some other implementations; use `-r` in older versions of GNU `sed`).

Comment: Ugh, the issue with hastily written questions when others are waiting for me to go to lunch: I only have one sed in the real command and the missing `*` is a typo as well. I'll edit the question to not confuse future readers, you might want to edit the answer. Not escaping the `^]` indeed works, thanks finswimmer!